# Can I change Gherkin formatting style in specflow?

Tags: formatting, specflow, gherkin

Can I change Gherkin formatting style in specflow? How can I do this?

Comment: You need to provide more details. An example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Given (ha!) this is the top google result, here where the settings are:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Fonts and Colours` > `Text Editor` > `Gherkin *`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you ask here, as pointed out by Roman, but there is a settings dialog in Visual Studio where you can tweak the formatting and colors.

See [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Integration) for more information